# Difference between Camera and Mediastore

Tags: android, android-camera

What is the difference between

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();
```

and

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

When should I use which?

Answer (score 0):

Camera Intent uses a Camera application to capture a picture. Usually, this would be the pre-installed Camera application. It opens the preview screen and allows the end-user to click the shutter. Your app can afterwards access the photo on disk. This intent takes quite a while.

Camera object may be used to control the camera inside your app, including video recording, on-the-fly video processing, etc. It can also be used to capture a photo, either when the end-user clicks a button, or if your program decides so (e.g. it recognizes a barcode). The photo will arrive to your callback function as a byte array, so you can save it on disk, or use it and discard it.